# campo que muestra nombre de usuario y contraseña erróneamente en opera

Tags: html

Tengo un campo, txtidentificacion_factura, de tipo textbox en asp.net, y veo que en opera, cuando el campo está en blanco, me pone erróneamente el nombre de usuario, como pensando que el campo es de usuario y contraseña.

El aspx es

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtidentificacion_factura" MaxLength="15" runat="server"/>
```

Si tengo grabado los campos para ese dominio, ¿le puedo decir que no me los muestre?

¿cómo sabe opera cuándo un campo es de usuario y contraseña?

Si relleno el campo con datos, me lo hace bien todo.

No sé por qué puede ser.

Muchísimas gracias por la posible ayuda.

PD: uso opera última versión. En los demás navegadores está bien, el campo está en blanco en un principio. No pasa nada malo, pero es molesto.

Comment: Tu duda es por el autocompletar? Significa que tienes datos guardados para ese dominio / página y tienes habilitado el autocompletar. Más allá de ésto, no sabemos más porque no sabemos cómo está armado tu formulario.

Answer (score 1):

> Si tengo grabado los campos para ese dominio, ¿le puedo decir que no me los muestre?

Afirmativo, si el problema es el autocompletar, puedes desactivarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="txtidentificacion_factura" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```